# Packing Ressources into Jar and accessing them

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, jar, executable-jar

I'm fairly new to Java and I'm having trouble exporting my application into a runnable jar. 
My application runs some transformations using Saxon and I want the stylesheets used to be inside the runnable jar.

Right now I simply have a subfolder in my project in eclipse and I'm accessing the stylesheets with that path. 
However as soon as I export the project as runnable jar inside that jar all the stylesheets are on the same level as the used libraries (subfolder is nowhere to be found.)

Also the application searches for that subfolder in the cwd and of course can't find it there.

How do I pack the stylesheets and access them properly inside the jar ?

//Update:

I think I'm a little further.

I've created a subfolder under src and put all stylesheets in there. I'm accessing them like so:

```
xsltexps = comp.compile(new StreamSource(new File(this.getClass().getResource("/stylesheets/" + stylesheets).toURI())));
```

If i run it in eclipse everything works fine. When I export it as runnable jar and run it i get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
>          at java.io.File.(Unknown Source)

I have no idea what that even means.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so here's what actually worked:

```
xsltexps = comp.compile(new StreamSource(
    getClass().getResourceAsStream("/stylesheets/" + stylesheets)));
```

Most importang change is the use of `getResourceAsStream` instead of `getResource`

Comment: Can you please tell me whether the stylesheet will be in binary format even if we extract the jar file. I have just asked a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919835/how-to-encode-data-of-xslt-stylesheet) like this a couple of minutes before. Can you please help me.

Comment: I see that question has already been answered. If you wan't to obfuscate your stylesheets this way is not for you, the stylesheet will be readable to everyone if extracted from the jar.