# How to encode data of XSLT stylesheet

Tags: java, jar, executable, xslt-2.0, executable-jar

I have generated an `XSLT` stylesheet which converts an `XML` file to an `ePub`. I use `saxon9.jar` to convert the `XML` using `XSLT`. Now I need to know whether I can make the `XSLT` code binary. Is it possible using `java`, so that I can generate a `jar` file which converts the `XML` to `ePub` using `saxon`, provided that the content of `XSLT` file is not readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem got resolved after I read this page: http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon7.6/using-xsl.html#Compiling

Comment: It is not at all clear to me that that kind of "compilation" is what you need.  My reading of that page is that the compiled templates are actually serialized Java objects, rather than Java ".class" files.  It would be relatively easy for someone to deserialize the serialized stylesheets ...

Comment: oh! I thought that the stylesheet is converted to binary format and the code cannot be decoded.

Comment: It says this: *"The file actually contains the Java serialization of a data structure that is then used at run-time to drive the transformation process."*

Comment: I an a novice in java.

Comment: *"I an a novice in java"* - all the more reason to carefully read up on how these things (e.g. Java serialization) work ... instead of just assuming things.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use Xalan-J XSLTC - https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/xsltc_usage.html.  Of course this is a different XSLT engine than Saxon ... and it appears that Xalan-J only supports XSLT-1.0 / XPATH-1.0.

I'm not sure, but it appears that Saxon-EE supports compilation of stylesheets to bytecode.  Saxon-EE not a free product though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obfuscate a stylesheet with Saxon you need the EE or PE edition, see http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!using-xsl/packaged-xslt, to create the obfuscated stylesheet. You can then run it however with Saxon HE.